# Difficulty chaining two UIView animations

Tags: objective-c

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish.

A UILabel will appear on screen at 100% alpha and move up 80pts using a UIView animation.   As soon as that animation ends, I want it to continue 80pts higher while fading out to alpha 0.  I want these two animations to appear as one seamless animation.

I thought maybe I could do this with a UIView animation and then put a second UIView animation in the completion block as shown below.    However,  there appears to be a delay before the completion block is executed which prevents the two animations from appearing seamless.

Can anyone tell me the best way to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^{   
    myLabel.center = endPoint;

}
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^{                
         myLabel.center = endPoint2;
         myLabel.alpha = 0;
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
             NSLog(@"animations complete");
     }];
 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I see no reason why not. Just a small addition, check for animation completion in `finished` block. As this will take care of any errors during animation. Also if you are planning to make this `UILabel` tappable then you need to make it so by setting the flag `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`.

```
   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{   
        myLabel.center = endPoint;
        myLabel.alpha = 1;
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if(finished){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{                
             myLabel.center = endPoint2;
             myLabel.alpha = 0;
            }
            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 NSLog(@"animations complete");
         }];
        }
     }];
```

Comment: It doesn't work... well it works, but its not the seamless effect I'm looking for.  It moves up 80 pixels... stops for a brief moment, then continues up the final 80 pixels and fades out.  I'm trying to get it to be seamless and not look like two animations.

Comment: I made one small edit to the code.. removed myLabel.alpha = 1 from first animation as it is already set to 1 before the animation  begins